# Where do model attributes get stored?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I searched a lot and can't find an answer.

Where the model object values are stored in `Spring` .

Where the `model.addAttributes("key","values")` values are stored *(eg : session , request)*.What is the scope of the this?

How I can get the values of the stored value in the JSP using the `expression language` like `${key}` ?

How the `EL` works to retrieve the stored values in the `model`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does the Spring Model that is passed to a JSP goes to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441729/where-does-the-spring-model-that-is-passed-to-a-jsp-goes-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the request, unless modified with a `@SessionAttributes`. If you're doing a redirect--request attributes are lost; it's a new request.
For your second and third question are addressed by this link [Where does the Spring Model that is passed to a JSP goes to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441729/where-does-the-spring-model-that-is-passed-to-a-jsp-goes-to)

Comment: Model attributes do not start out stored in the request or in the session.

Answer (score 4):

The `DispatcherServlet`, which is the entry point of any Spring MVC application, creates a new [`ModelAndViewContainer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html) object on each request. The javadoc for this class states

> Records model and view related decisions made by 
>   `HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers` and `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlers`
>   during the course of invocation of a controller method.

Those two interfaces are what handles resolving your `@RequestMapping` annotated method arguments and return values.

So, during the lifecycle of the request, the model attributes are stored in a [`ModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) field of this `ModelAndViewContainer` object. The actual, current, implementation is a [`BindingAwareModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/support/BindingAwareModelMap.html).

Towards the end of the request, when a view needs to be rendered, some `View` objects will merge the model attributes with the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

> How the EL works to retrieve the stored values in the model?

It doesn't. EL resolves the attributes from the JSP's page scope,`HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession`, or `ServletContext`.